# npm reports an incorrect version for my module

Tags: javascript, node.js, github, npm

**tl;dr** : the reported version in [npmjs.org](https://npmjs.org/package/network-constants) is not the same as the one in [`package.json`](https://github.com/Offirmo/network-constants.js/blob/master/package.json). Why ?

---

I have a javascript module that I released in both npm and bower : https://github.com/Offirmo/network-constants.js

It has a `package.json` for npm and a `bower.json` for bower. Both files have a `version` field, currently set to "0.9.2" in both files.

I recently added nice badges on the github readme. Then I noticed some discrepencies in the reported version : npm badge reported "0.9.0" and bower badge reported "undefined".

I managed to figure that bower was looking a the latest git tag to figure out the version, and it works for bower now. (though it wasn't documented)

However, it still doesn't work for npm. And this is not a badge issue : when I look at this module in the npm repository here https://npmjs.org/package/network-constants it also incorrectly reports "0.9.0" instead of "0.9.2".

I have looked everywhere on npm site to try to figure out how the version was fetched, with no success.

So how does npm figures out the current version of my module ? How do I fix the discrepency between package.json and npmjs.org ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

npm says that you published only once and it was version `0.9.0` on 2013-11-26. github says that you update `package.json` to `0.9.2` 18 days ago. So, did you `npm publish` after you released `0.9.2`?

Comment: So `npm publish` is not only for the initial release ? The doc is totally unclear ! https://npmjs.org/doc/cli/npm-publish.html Thanks !